# Failing while writing data into a dataframe from API

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, error-handling, iteration

I have an API to which pass the certain value and retrieve cerrtain values from Python.

I am doing an iterative call to API and getting the values and storing to the dataframe.

```
**Perfect Working  Format Passing Values to API**
cities = ['BUSAN','SACHEON','SINGAPORE','RIO GRANDE','GUANGZHOU']
```

But In my real data scenario , I have invalid values for which I dont response from API. How can I handle expections

```
cities = ['BUSAN','XCBZ','999BB','GUANGZHOU']
```

The API fails with message with  like below

```
{"message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."}\n'
```

My code

This code works perfectly when are only correct values and but fails when API is not able find a value

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
cities = ['BUSAN','XWY','999','GUANGZHOU'] 
df_results = pd.DataFrame( list(zip( cities)), columns =[ 'City'])
results ={}
df_results["lat"] = ""
df_results["lon"] = ""

for i, row in df_results.iterrows():
    d_ = "{{ \"address\" : \"{0}\" }}".format(str(row["City"]))
    response = requests.post('https://example.com', headers=headers, params=params, data=d_)
    d = json.loads(response.text)
    df_results["lat"].iloc[i]=d['position']['lat']
    df_results["lon"].iloc[i]=d['position']['lon']
```

**MY expected Output**

```
City       lat   lon
BUSAN      1.234 10.234
XWY        NaN   NaN
999        NaN   NaN
GUANGZHOU  1.345 8.456
```

How can handle this expection handling?

Comment: After working on APIs for the last month I would HIGHLY recommend implementing `jsonschema`. Its great for validating API calls.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, I have not written the API. I just permissions to call the API. Due you know how fix my situation

Answer (score 0):

Used the `Response Status code` from the API to handle expections and now it works fine

```
results ={}
df_results["lat"] = ""
df_results["lon"] = ""
for i, row in df_results.iterrows():
    d_ = "{{ \"address\" : \"{0}\" }}".format(str(row["City"]))
    response = requests.post('https://example.com/geocoder/geocode', headers=headers, params=params, data=d_)
    if (response.status_code)!=200:
        #print("Error: Unexpected response {}".format(response))
        df_results["lat"].iloc[i]="NA"
        df_results["lon"].iloc[i]="NA"
    elif (response.status_code)==200:
        d = json.loads(response.text) 
        df_results["lat"].iloc[i]=d['position']['lat']
        df_results["lon"].iloc[i]=d['position']['lon']
```